# Dereferencing raw pointer with explicit annotation in Rust

Tags: pointers, memory-management, rust, unsafe-pointers

I was writing unsafe snippet of code to emulate how C would have allocated a memory for an `int`. The code allocates memory for an `isize` type, assign `0` to the pointer variable, then infinitely increment the value at the address every second

```
use std::process;
use std::{thread, time};
use std::alloc::{alloc, Layout};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let layout = Layout::new::<isize>();
        let p = alloc(layout);
        println!("({}) address pointed to by p: {:p}", process::id(), p);
        *(p as *mut isize) = 0;
        loop {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
            *(p as *mut isize) += 1;
            println!("({}) p: {}", process::id(), *(p as *mut isize));
        }
    }
}
```

However, for each `*(p as *mut size)` I could have replaced with just `*p` without the compiler complaining (i.e. `*p = 0;`), thus I assumed it was correctly inferred. I need help explaining the difference and in which case the explicit type annotation may be required.

Comment: If you want to know what type the compiler inferred for a variable, just put `let () = variable;` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you @SebastianRedl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correctly inferred. [`alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/alloc/fn.alloc.html) returns a pointer to `u8`, which can be set to 0 or incremented, so the compiler doesn't complain. However it will wrap at 255 instead of wrapping at 4G (or whatever if you're on a 64-bit system).